# Open an application in a LAN desktop using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, unix, lan

Yesterday I could successfully connect to a Unix server from my Windows PC using the following script:

```
**import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('punltc02.force.com',username = 'amkar',password = 'new')
stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command("pwd") (it works !!)

>>> stdout.readlines()

[u'/home/amkar\n'
```

---

Today, I am trying to do the same thing but instead of a Unix server I am trying to connect to a Windows desktop from my laptop. I need to connect to the desktop and start running an application using Python. I am getting the following error:

```
*`enter code here`*>>> ssh.connect('135.24.237.144',username =     
'administrator',password = 'force')
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 251, in  
 connect
 retry_on_signal(lambda: sock.connect(addr))
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\util.py", line 270, in   
 retry_on_signal
 return function()
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 251, in   
 <lambda>
  retry_on_signal(lambda: sock.connect(addr))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 224, in meth
  return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
  error: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target   
  machine actively refused it**
```

I doubt whether I need to install OpenSSH in the LAN desktop too. Or, there are other ways to do this. Please help.

Thanks and regards,
Amitra

Comment: Is there a SSH server running on the desktop?

Comment: I need to check that. Just now I found that I am able to: ping the desktop and also do MSTSC. But I am unable to connect through WinSCP.

Comment: Ping tells you that one computer can reach another. If there is no SSH server running and you try to connect with SSH, SCP or SFTP, your data frame will reach that computer and it will be refused since there is no software running there to understand it and process it.

Comment: @user3565150 as Bartosz mentioned you need to have a SSH service running on the LAN computer. Because windows machine doesn't have any SSH service running by default. You have to install some SSH service.

Comment: Thank you !! I will install SSH and try again

Comment: Hi, I was able to install SSH using Cygwin on the LAN desktop and from my pc I tried to connect and got the following: ssh.connect('135.24.237.142',username = 'cyg_server',password = 'force') stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command("pwd")
stdout.readlines()
[u'/var/empty\n'] ..... Can you please tell me how can I move from here and run a required application like "C:\Program Files (x86)\Tensilica\Xtensa OCD Daemon 9.0.3"" ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to install OpenSSH on the LAN desktop.

Also if already installed OpenSSH then try disabling the firewall. Ping the remote computer to check if there is a connectivity between your machine and the remote machine.

you could use [Paramiko](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/1.15/index.html) to execute the remote application. You may use the [ssh.exec_command()](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/1.15/api/channel.html#paramiko.channel.Channel.exec_command) For eg:

```
import paramiko    
sh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.connect(server, username=username, password=password)
ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh.exec_command(cmd_to_execute_on_remote_machine)
```

Other possibility is [PsExec](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe such as this?
http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/creating-undetectable-custom-ssh-backdoor-python-z/

```
import paramiko
import threading
 
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('10.0.2.15', username='root', password='toor')
chan = ssh.get_transport().open_session()
chan.send('Hey i am connected :) ')
print chan.recv(1024)
client.close
```